# Is there any documentation available for Hydrograph Tool?

Tags: github

I want to understand how to start using the Hydrograph Tool (GitHub link below). There is no wiki associated with this project couldn't find any  steps to compile/build the repo code.

https://github.com/capitalone/Hydrograph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the installation guide. I haven't tried it myself, so can't tell you for sure if there are any gotchas with the installation process.

https://capitalone.github.io/Hydrograph//localInstall

Comment: Thanks @shakhawat. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this open source tool? Is it practicable? Also I see that they are removing it from the website from 31st onwards. I don't want to indulge into something that is going to be closed soon. - ira wati.

Comment: Actually, I don't have expertise on best practices and available tools for ETL. I highly recommend you to research yourself more and reach out to experience people on this particular field to get better suggestions. Best wishes!!

Comment: Thanks @shakhawat. - ira wati

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to check the readme file? There is a clear link - 
https://github.com/capitalone/Hydrograph/blob/master/README.md

> https://developer.capitalone.com/opensource-projects/hydrograph/

Comment: Yes @Amit, That was the first file I looked into it. Unfortunately, it does not contain anything related to how to install and get going. Shakhawat provided the link in his answer - ira wati.