# Why does the Hydrograph Build process builds 2 additional OS versions of the tool?

Tags: github

Using the installation guide [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406658/is-there-any-documentation-available-for-hydrograph-tool) provided by one of the stack overflow user, I have build Hydrograph on my machine.

I followed the steps line by line as per the document to compile the Hydrograph git code and found that it generates 3 different versions of Hydrograph (macOS, Windows and Linux). This consumed almost 2 GB of additional space on my Mac. I do not need Windows and Linux version. Is this correct behavior of the compilation/build process??

Before reaching out to stack overflow community, I had reported the issue on [Hydrograph](https://github.com/capitalone/Hydrograph) public GitHub repository but haven't got any response.

Reported Issue is [here](https://github.com/capitalone/Hydrograph/issues/157).

-ira wati

Comment: This feels like this question would be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com/) as its more about the general tools than about the programming.

Comment: @Jouster500 I do not think so because "Super User is not about programming and software development" while asking about a build setup is very related to software developement. I think this question can stay here, but it is unlikely that it will be answered before the Github issue is.

Comment: weird capitalization, old name for the Mac's OS

Answer (score 0):

The Hydrograph(UI) is designed to work on Windows, mac and linux OS(and tested very well for Windows 64bit and Mac). That's why it has POM which creates different builds for OS,Windows and Mac. You can update the POM to create build for specific OS.